# Should we get rid of [new-years]?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags

The [new-years](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-years) tag's description is:

> A new year's puzzle is any puzzle that is posted around the first day of any year that has to do with that specific year or calendars in some way.

This isn't really an objective tag. Its questions include:

- Time-based questions usually based around years

  - [Eternal 2014](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/43045/eternal-2014-pcg-se-new-year-s-puzzle-2015), which asks you to convert standard dates to a format where the year is never greater than 2014
  - [What year is it?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/43044/what-year-is-it), whichs asks you to determine a year for a December calendar
  - [Advance Happy New Year, 2016!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66656/advance-happy-new-year-2016), which asks you to find the next year where New Year's day falls on the same weekday
- Questions that involve printing the year in some format with some sort of restrictions

  - [Morse the new year](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/43115/morse-the-new-year), which asks you to output a MIDI file of the Morse Code of "2016"
  - The famous [2014 without numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17005/produce-the-number-2014-without-any-numbers-in-your-source-code), which asks you to print 2014 without numbers.
  - [Write a program that outputs 2012 even if it's modified](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/write-a-program-that-always-outputs-2012-even-if-its-modified)
- Questions with a year chucked in

  - [Grow Till It's 2017](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105213/grow-till-its-2017) - asks to create a program that grows until length 2017, which could be any number
  - [Recycling for the New Year](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/43048/recycling-for-the-new-year) - asks you to rearrange a program to create one that outputs 2015
  - [Write a program that sees the New Year in itself](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/197679/write-a-program-that-sees-the-new-year-in-itself) - Asks you to create a injection from strings to outputs such that it maps itself to 2020, which could be any number
- Various random stuff

  - [Happy new year string builder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242683/happy-new-year-string-builder), which asks you to create a string  in a certain format such that the character code sum is a certain number
  - [Mine for 2016 in bitcoin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/68320/mine-for-2016-in-bitcoins-pcg-se-new-years-puzzle-2016), which ask you to bruteforce SHA256 hashes until you find one containing `2016`

This seems to be more of a [meta-tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/). When you have a question tagged with [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) you know the question involves the use and manipulation of strings. But when you have a question tagged with [new-years](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-years) there's many things it could be about, as you can see above, and knowing that a question is related to the new year gives little to no useful information.

So, what should we do with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Burn it.

Looks like the first category of challenges do fit the tag description, but keeping a tag that applies to a very small number of posts and gets used incorrectly more often doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: Note that because burnination requires a dev, we've instead merged it into [code-golf].